# Powershell for Scheduled tasks

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to gather all the info from our scheduled tasks by powershell.
I would like to get not only the name, action and the times but also the full schedule of when its going to run.
E.g Mon 12:00, Tue 13:00, Wed 14:00.
I have run a number of scripts and have the times that the tasks run but not what days they are set to.
Does anyone know how to get what days a task is set to?

Comment: Try `(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName MyTask).Triggers`.

Comment: I have tried that and have $ScheduledTasks = get-scheduledtask |  ? {$_.TaskPath -eq '\'} as part of my larger script.
I can get the times a task gets triggered, but not what days.